# Excluding sub-folders when uploading files to an Azure container on blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure's [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python) in Python to upload a file into a container on Azure blob storage. Here's the example:

```
def upload_blob_file(self, blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, container_name: str):
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)
    with open(file=os.path.join('filepath', 'filename'), mode="rb") as data:
        blob_client = container_client.upload_blob(name="sample-blob.txt", data=data, overwrite=True)
```

When I run this on a Mac, in the container on Azure, I only see the file itself uploaded. However, when I run the very code on a Windows machine (10 Pro, in my case,) I see that all sub-folders also get uploaded with the file. For example, let's say my container's name on Azure is `container1` and the file I want to upload to Azure is stored on my local machine in the following path: `/Users/[my-username]/PycharmProjects/project1/data/file1.txt`. When I run the code on:

- Mac, container content on Azure: `container1/file1.txt`
- Windows, container content on Azure: `container1/C/Users/[my-username]/PycharmProjects/project1/data/file1.txt`

How can I exclude the folders and sub-folders that are also created on my blob storage when I run the code from Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried below python code to upload a blob to my storage account container in Windows.***

I made changes in the **file_name = os.path.basename(local_file_path)** is working for excluding the folders and sub-folders.

**Code:**

```py
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def UploadBlobFile(blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, ContainerName: str):
    ContainerClient = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=ContainerName)
    local_file_path = 'path/to/sample-blob.txt'
    file_name = os.path.basename(local_file_path)
    with open(file=local_file_path, mode="rb") as data:
        blob_client = ContainerClient.upload_blob(name=file_name, data=data, overwrite=True)

Connec_string = '<storage_connec_string>'
ContainerName = '<container_name>'

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(Connec_string)
UploadBlobFile(blob_service_client, ContainerName)
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

***Blob uploaded successfully to my storage account container in Azure portal as below,***

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently, I was making a mistake when passing the file name. I replaced the file name with `file_name = os.path.basename(local_file_path)` and the problem was solved!